# AlpineJs dynamically changing nested component

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

What are the options to keep nested components reactive.

I have very little experience with **alpineJs** and need some advice.
There is a filter in which items are dynamically changed during the search.
I bypass these elements with `x-for`.
This is where I run into a problem. For example, for the item.range position, I need to use a different **library** (for example, **Ion.RangeSlider**), the problem is that initialization occurs only once and, accordingly, with subsequent changes in `items`, the `item.range` position that is in `x-for` will not change and remain static .

I see several options here:

1. It is trivial to wrap the rendering of this position in the `isLoading` condition, and on each load, the initialization will occur anew and, accordingly, the actual data will be displayed. But this is clearly not the right decision, for a number of reasons.

```
<template x-if="item.hasRange && !isLoading" >
    <div x-data="item(index)">
        <input x-ref="range" type="text" />
        <template x-data="range($refs.range)"></template>
    </div>
</template>
```

2. Implement a wrapper on top of this library with its api methods, and try to pass data already in them.

Below is a slightly truncated version of the code.

```
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.data('filter', () => ({
        items: [],
        item_: (index) => {
            return {
                item: this.items[index];
                range: () => {
                    return {
                        range: null,
                        init() {
                            this.range = range(element) {
                                $(element).ionRangeSlider({
                                    type: "double",
                                    //...
                                    onFinish: (data) => {},//...
                                });
                            }
                        },
                        update: () => {
                            this.range.update(/*...*/);
                        },
                        //... other api
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    })
})
```

3. Implement an event listener in a component that implements rendering using an external library

I would be very grateful for an example or information on how best to implement such dynamism.

Comment: It blew my mind that this isn't supported in Alpine JS, considering it apparently uses Vue's reactivity engine. However, the only way I could get something like this to work, is that whenever a nested object changed, I had to re-bind the original array with the new values. It's a pita.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to include an external library is to write a [custom directive](https://alpinejs.dev/advanced/extending) or a custom magic component. This way we can have an Alpine.js-like API for the external library with two-way data binding and we can reuse our component easily elsewhere.

Here I show a minimal example that implements a double RangeSlider with min/max modifiers as e.g. `x-range.min.0.max.10="item.range"` custom directive. I added further explanations as inline comments, so see the live example and source code:

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.1/css/ion.rangeSlider.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.1/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>


<div x-data="{items: [
  {id: 1, range: {from: 2, to: 3, updating: false}},
  {id: 2, range: {from: 3, to: 4, updating: false}},
  {id: 3, range: {from: 4, to: 5, updating: false}},
  ]}">

  <template x-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
      <input type="text" x-range.min.0.max.10="item.range" />
      <div><b x-text="`Item #${item.id} Range: ${item.range.from}-${item.range.to}`"></b>,
        Set manually: from: <input type="number" x-model="item.range.from" min="0" max="10" size="1">
        to: <input type="number" x-model="item.range.to" min="0" max="10" size="1">
        <span x-show="item.range.updating">Changing...</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.directive('range', (el, { expression, modifiers }, { evaluate, evaluateLater, effect }) => {
    // Set RangeSlider config from directive modifiers
    const config = {
      type: "double",

      onChange(data) {
        // Disable Alpine.js->RangeSlider data flow during RangeSlider change event
        evaluate(`${expression}.updating = true;`)

        // Update Alpine.js data after range change
        evaluate(`${expression}.from = ${data.from}; ${expression}.to = ${data.to}`)
      },

      onFinish(data) {
        // Enable Alpine.js->RangeSlider data flow again after a RangeSlider change event
        evaluate(`${expression}.updating = false;`)
      },
    }

    // Source: https://github.com/ryangjchandler/alpine-tooltip
    const getModifierArgument = (modifier) => {
      return modifiers[modifiers.indexOf(modifier) + 1]
    }

    if (modifiers.includes('min')) {
      config.min = getModifierArgument('min')
    }

    if (modifiers.includes('max')) {
      config.max = getModifierArgument('max')
    }

    if (!el.__x_range) {
      // Init RangeSlider on the element
      el.__x_range = $(el).ionRangeSlider(config)

      // Set RangeSlider data for updating it from Alpine.js
      el.__x_range_data = el.__x_range.data("ionRangeSlider")
    }

    // Set Alpine.js data binding that updates RangeSlider
    let rangeData = evaluateLater(expression)
    
    effect(() => {
      // Update RangeSlider data from Alpine.js data when RangeSlider is inactive
      rangeData(val => {
        if (!val.updating) el.__x_range_data.update({ from: val.from, to: val.to })
      })
    })
  })
})
</script>
```

Comment: This looks really interesting, thanks for taking the time to explain!

As far as I understand, I can also pass callback functions in the same way?
In order, for example, to be able to interact from the outside with the data that comes in functions such as onChange(), onFinish()
Thank you!

Comment: For example like this:
`<input x-range={} x-range._callbackOnChange="(data) => {console.log(data)}"/>`


`onChange(data) {
     evaluate(<quote>${expression}._callbackOnChange(${data});</quote>)
},

if (modifiers.includes('_callbackOnChange')) {
    config._callbackOnChange = getModifierArgument('_callbackOnChange')
}`

Comment: Yes, technically you can pass anything that can be evaluated. However I wouldn't do that because it makes the template code cluttered. Instead of that you can additional properties to the `range` object. In my example I used 3 properties: `from, to, updating`. You can interact with these data anywhere in your component. In your custom directive you can check whether the provided data object has a specific property and activate additional functionalities based on that. So you can expose the whole external library like this and activate part of the functionalies based on the passed data object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `x-show` instead of `x-if`, with this you can then manually hide or show the component using CSS.

```
<div x-data="{ items: [], activeIndex: null }">
  <template x-for="(item, index) in items">
    <div x-show="activeIndex === index" x-bind:key="index">
      <input x-ref="range" type="text" x-bind:value="item.range" x-on:input="item.range = $event.target.value" />
      <template x-init="initRange($refs.range, item.range)">
        <!-- initialization code here -->
      </template>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
The question is not what to show or not. An example with a condition was given only as an option that, through a crutch, but can reinitialize a component with already up-to-date data.

Comment: maybe you can try used $nextTick for this